# How to delete a single View inside a ScrollView

Tags: android, android-view, android-scrollview, android-viewgroup

I have a *ScrollView* inside my activity, to which `Views` are added during runtime. Basically, when the player defines his name and gender (and names and genders of other players) and then clicks the plus button, then three elements are added to a single line inside the *ScrollView*: **one ImageView** for the gender (which contains either male or female icon), **a TextView** to display the player's name and a **delete button** at the end of the line, so this player can be deleted, for example if the user mistyped the player's name.

If `n` is the number of players that are added (or the number the plus button has been clicked), then the number of Views inside the ScrollView is `n*3`.

After the plus button to add the player is clicked, I also create a *PlayerDraft* instance, which contains the name of the player, the player's gender and three integers corresponding to views that are associated with the player (one int for the id of the corresponding icon, one int for the id of the corresponding text view, which represents the player's name and one int for the id of the delete button associated with the player).

I also keep track between the `id`s of the delete buttons and this *PlayerDraft* instances in a hashmap. This way, when a certain delete button is clicked, I can use it's `id` to find the corresponding *PlayerDraft* instance and therefore also the `id`s of the *View*s associated with this player inside the *ScrollView*.

This is the code that is called each time a certain delete button is clicked (this is basically inside a method which I call on every delete button that is added to set it's on click listener instance ... this code is inside the `setOnClickListener` method):

```
public void onClick(View v)
    //delete corresponding player gender icon, player name and the delete button itself
    PlayerDraft playerToDelete = idToPlayer.get(v.getId());
    if(null != playerToDelete) {
            ImageView iconToDelete = findViewById(playerToDelete.getIconViewId());
            TextView textToDelete = findViewById(playerToDelete.getNameViewId());
            Button b = (Button) v;

            Log.d("thc", "Icon id that is to be deleted: " + iconToDelete.getId());
            Log.d("thc", "name view id that is to be deleted: " + textToDelete.getId());
            Log.d("thc", "delete button id to be deleted: " + b.getId());

            player_display_view.removeView(iconToDelete);
            player_display_view.removeViewInLayout(textToDelete);
            player_display_view.removeViewInLayout(b);

            //player_display_view.removeViewAt(0);
            //player_display_view.removeAllViews()

            Log.d("thc", "Number of elements in player_display_view scrollview: " + player_display_view.getChildCount());
    } else {
       Log.d("thc", "playerToDelete is null!");
    }
}
```

**The problem is that calling `player_display_view.removeView(iconToDelete)` or any similar thereof method doesn't work!** However, calling `player_display_view.removeAllViews()` works.

I've discovered the following problem. The `player_display_view` *ScrollView* always contains only one child and that child is at position 0 in it's array of children. The number of children doesn't change no matter how much views are added to the *ScrollView* during runtime, which just boggles my ming :/. How can the *View*s even be displayed inside the *ScrollView* (they are, testing it on my phone), if they aren't specified as children of that *ScrollView*? Calling the method `player_display_view.removeViewAt(0);` to delete this only child view inside the ScrollView, deletes not only one *View* of the `ScrollView`, but ALL of the added views.

**Why is the following happening? Why does the ScrollView contain only one child, despite multiple Views are added to it during runtime? How can I delete specific Views inside the ScrollView?**

Thank you for the time taken, I really appreciate it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In general, a `ScrollView` contains only one child. This is usually a container (like `LinearLayout` or `RelativeLayout`) that is scrolled by the `ScrollView`. If you are dynamically (programatically) adding `View`s to a `ScrollView`, it has probably created an internal container `Layout` to hold your added views.

You should put a `Layout` inside your `ScrollView` and manage (add/delete) your `View`s inside that `Layout`. Then your "delete" code should work.

Comment: Thank you, your solution has worked! I've introduced another variable, which is of type LinearLayout and called it player_display_layout and got it by accessing the only child of the ScrollView (which is this default-created linear layout). Then, calling removeView on this linear layout (player_display_layout) produces the desired results. Thank you!